# AngularJS - Possible to use $filter for Translation inside the RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor?

Tags: angularjs, filter, internationalization, translation

We are still working with AngularJS! We want so translate all the error messages sending from Responce or from Core. We already use translation with i18n. We want to implement the translation for the error messages inside the RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor. If this possible we have only one place to change!
This is the code for the Provider

```
export const config = ['RestangularProvider', function (RestangularProvider) {
    // Add response handler to normal response
    RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
        handlerResponseStatus(response);
        return data;
    });

    // Add error handler to restangular response
    RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor(function (response, deferred, responseHandler) {
        handlerResponseStatus(response);
        return true;
    });
}];
```

and this a part of the function handlerResponseStatus:

```
function handlerResponseStatus(response) {
var message = '';
    var type = 'info';
    var title = 'Request Info';

    //1) Unhandled exception
    if (response.data && response.data.responseStatus) {
        if (response.data.responseStatus.message) {
            message = response.data.responseStatus.message;
        }

        if (response.data.responseStatus.type) {
            type = response.data.responseStatus.type;
        }

        if (response.data.responseStatus.title) {
            title = response.data.responseStatus.title;
        }

        // Publish notify event to show popup
        events.publish('notify', { 'type': type, 'message': message, 'title': title, 'debug': response.data.requestDebug });
    }
}
```

We want to translate the message and the title.
Thanks a lot

The $filter is not available in this context ans i had no idea anymore how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can not inject any serivice here, you can inject another provider `$injector` and inside callback get your `$filter`:

```
export const config = ['RestangularProvider', '$injector', function (RestangularProvider, $injector) {
    // $injector.get('$filter') will throw error if called here
    RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
        const $filter = $injector.get('$filter'); // Here $filter is initialized already
        handlerResponseStatus(response, $filter);
        return data;
    });
```